# How to Get a Specific Song From the Phone's MediaLibrary? And optimising the code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, playback, media-library

In my application I have the following code, which get's the phone's `MediaLibrary` and filters out the correct chosen `Song` from the `MediaLibrary.Songs` and plays it:

```
using (MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary())
{
    foreach (var item in library.Songs)
    {
        if (item.Name == songName)
        {
            FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
            MediaPlayer.Play(item);
        }
    }
    library.Dispose();
}
```

However this takes quite a while and results in a pause. Is there a faster/more-efficient way to access a specific `Song` from the phone's `MediaLibrary.Songs`?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have to store the values in a XML document after you read the directory, this can save you a lot of time if the library doesn't get changed (Check the size of the whole library). If it does then you can check the library again and update your XML.

Comment: are XML documents permanent like IsolatedStorage? as if they are that would be impractical as most people have 4GB+ of music stored on their phone.

Comment: XML docs are the best way to list out and organize the contents of the phone, the size of the library doesn't matter, what matters is that that library needs to be scanned only once, the contents are gonna be listed out in an XMl format and can be loaded any time the user re-launches the player. This can significantly increase the loading speed. You should know that foreach loops are very fast and if you go for other techniques like Linq, your program may slow down to some extent. So the only solution that comes to my mind, like the rest of mp3 players, is to list out the content.

Comment: You couldn't add a link on how to store in XML format could you?

Comment: @user2696648 I'm sure if you search XML Playlist in google you will get a lot of results.

Comment: Fair enough, will do that then

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not an efficient way at all.
To find any song in `MediaLibrary` use **LINQ**.
Example

```
MediaPlayer.Play(library.Songs.First(x=>x.Name == songName));
```